# How can I delete/update a row in jqgrid when it has no "id" value?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have found that I am able to add rows to the jqgrid that have no ID value assigned.
--This is good, because I would prefer to assign this value later on the server-side.

However, I am unable to select such rows in the jqgrid, i.e., in order to perform a client-side delete/update operation.
Though, I ***can*** access the "***iRow***" value when I double-click
i.e.,

```
ondblClickRow: function(id, iRow, iCol, e)
```

--But, I do not know how to highlight or delete/update a row using this "iRow" value.

QUESTION: How can I select/highlight and ultimately update/delete rows that have no "id" value assigned?

For example, below, is how I have been able to successfully update a selected row that ***already*** has an "id" value assigned...

```
var datarow = {theId: $("#theId").val(), something1: $("#something1").val(), something2: $("#something2").val()};
$("#mygrid").jqGrid('setRowData', $("#theId").val(), datarow);
```

-- Again, how would I delete a selected row that has ***no*** id assigned?

Appreciate any help/direction on this.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you adding rows without a rowID? That should be a separate piece of information from the id of your record.

Comment: Essentially like this:  var datarow = {theId: '', something1: $("#something1").val(), something2: $("#something2").val()};
$("#mygrid").jqGrid('setRowData', '', datarow);  (though, technically, a zero-length string might be considered a legitimate ID)

Comment: @sairn: It is **incorrect value** for `id`. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp#gsc.tab=0) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Moreover id value as empty string is not the same no id. You can verify that it follows to creating `id` attribute with `""` (empty string) as the value. If you have more as one rows with the value you will get id duplicates which is another error which break HTML standards. So the way which you posted is definitively wrong.

Comment: Thank you, Oleg.  Your point is taken.  Being new to jqgrid - it is clear that I've learned only enough to be "dangerous", thus far.   Thanks again for your kind attention to my question/post (and, as well, thanks for your service to the jquery/jqgrid community!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid can't use rows of data which has no `id`. All internal callbacks and internal functions works only with rows having ids.

If you need to add row which id should be assigned later by the server you have to add row with some id and just change the id later after the server response. For example the method [addRow](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L409-L444) uses `$.jgrid.randId()` to generate unique rowid for temporary new row. jqGrid add class `jqgrid-new-row` additionally to the new row. In the code fragment in my bug report [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/save-button-of-inlinenav-uses-editparams-instead-of-addparams-addrowparams-on-add-new-row/#p28525) you can find how the `id` of the row could be changed later after the server return new id of the row generated in the database.

Comment: Thank you, Oleg. You do understand the issue I am facing(I.e., the db generated ID).  I'll take a look at the links you provided.